# Как задать собственный стиль для IE8 или заставить его отображать скругленные углы разного радиуса?

Tags: css3

Здравствуйте.

Вот такая у меня задача. Проблему со скругленными углами для IE6-7 я решил установив им собственные стили, а как то же сделать для 8го не знаю. Либо нужно как-то в 8-м отобразить скругл. углы блока с разными радиусами...

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](http://prootime.ru/css-zakruglennie-ugli) посмотри.